# How to Send Value from android app to Arduino Bluetooth HC-05

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arduino, bluetooth

I am making an android app using android studio ,

I want to send value 'string or Integer' to arduino pro mini via bluetooth hc-05.

The bluetooth hc-05 will already be connected (paired) to the android device .

Can you please help me to make a simple code that send the value via bluetooth?
Thank you so much.

Comment: That's not a question, you're asking for somebody else to solve your problem. Try breaking it in pieces, try something, even if you know it won't work, so you will have specific question that we can help you with.

Comment: This platform is not to asking someone to make you a sample code. Instead, it is helping someone if they having programming problems.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easiest way to implement that is to use a third-party library like this [BluetoothLibrary](https://github.com/OmarAflak/Bluetooth-Library).

- Include the library dependency into your `app module` gradle file.
- set up the library in your app as described in the library's repository on GitHub.
- If you need to connect to the device from the app you have to implement the scanning functionality yourself by providing a `ListView` and the logic to insert the discovered Bluetooth devices.
- If you prefer to follow the easy way just connect to the Bluetooth device externally from your device's Bluetooth manager, then you can communicate with the device as follows.

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    bluetooth = new Bluetooth(this);
    bluetooth.send("Your message");

}
```

- If you want to receive back some response from the other Bluetooth device you have to listen to the `DeviceCallback()` you will find its description in the Github repository

### Note

You have to add some permissions in the Manifest files which are

- BLUETOOTH
- BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
- ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

In order to give the access to your app to use the bluetooth